# Jsoup get comment before element

Tags: java, jsoup

Say I have this html:

```
<!-- some comment -->
<div class="someDiv">
... other html
</div>
<!-- some comment 2 -->
<div class="someDiv">
... other html
</div>
```

I'm currently getting all divs where class == someDiv and scraping them for information.  To do that I'm simply doing this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements elements = doc.select(".someDiv");
for (Element element : elements) {
    //scrape stuff
}
```

Within the for loop, is there any way to get the comment tag found before the particular div.someDiv element I'm on?

If this isn't possible, should I go about parsing this html structure differently with this requirement?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4):

Though this question is a few month old here my answer for completeness. How about using `previousSibling` to get the preceding `Node`. Of course in the real code you probably want to check, whether you really get a `Comment` there.

```
String html = "<!-- some comment --><div class=\"someDiv\">... other html</div><!-- some comment 2 --><div class=\"someDiv\">... other html</div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
Elements elements = doc.select(".someDiv");
for (Element element : elements) {
    System.out.println(((Comment) element.previousSibling()).getData());
}
```

This produces:

```
some comment 
some comment 2
```

(tested with jsoup 1.6.1 and 1.6.3)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, Iterate over all comments and check if their *sibling* is the div you were after

```
for (int i = 0; i < doc.childNodes().size(); i++) {
        Node child = doc.childNode(i);
        if (child.nodeName().equals("#comment")) {
            //do some checking on child.nextSibling() , like hasAttr or attr to figure out if it the div you were expecting for...
        }
}
```

Take a look at the [jsoup Node docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html)

Answer (score 0):

Elements elements = doc.select("div.someDiv");

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/

Comment: Not sure if you missed the question, but I'm already getting all the divs with class someDiv.